# How to set "approved" user attribute to true with a button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model established by Devise and it has a Boolean attribute "approved" with default value set to false.

I created a separate controller called "newcomers" where I set `index` action to display all not approved users and `update` action to set "approved" to true

```
class NewcomersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @users = User.where("approved = ?", false)
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.update_attribute :approved, true
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to newcomers_path, notice: 'Member was successfully approved!' }
        end
    end
end
```

So, in my view I did

```
<h1>Members Requests</h1>

<% @users.each do |user| %> 
<%= user.email %>

<%= form_for user, url: newcomers_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

and in my routes I have resources :newcomers

[image]

So, I do not know how to make the button work the way it should. Meaning it should just update the attribute "approved" and set it to true. and return to the same page (index)

Comment: use `link_to` tag with `remote: true` from your controller respond block and handle response in js.you can take reference from here https://github.com/uzaif313/user-app

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
<h1>Members Requests</h1>

<% @users.each do |user| %> 
  <%= user.email %>
  <% if user.approved %>
    <%= link_to 'Unapprove', newcomer_path(user, approve: false), method: :put %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Approve', newcomer_path(user, approve: true ), method: :put %>
  <% end %>
```

## controller

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute :approved, params[:approve]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to newcomers_path, notice: 'Member was successfully approved!' }
    end
end
```

Comment: goes here /newcomers.3?approve=true
and tells me that there is a routing error No route matches [PUT] "/newcomers.3"

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `link_to` in your view an point it to the update action in your controller:

`<%= link_to 'Approve', newcomer_path(user_id), method: :put %>`

In your controller just update the user with the given id an redirect to index path as you already do.

If you want it somewhat more fancy you can add a `remote: true` to your `link_to` and respond with an js to delete only the affected row from your view.

Comment: it just sends me to localhost:3000/newcomers.3 (where 3 is a user.id) and does nothing at all. This is what i am struggling with.

Comment: in routes i have resources :newcomers which should generate all necessary links. If i add method: :put i get an error

No route matches [PUT] "/newcomers.3"

Answer (score 1):

Make below changes

In view

```
<%= form_for user, url: newcomer_path(user, approved: true), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
<% end %>
```

and in controller

```
def update
    if params[:user].nil?
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.update_attribute :approved, true
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to newcomers_path, notice: 'Member was successfully approved!' }
      end
    end
end
```

let me know if it is not working...